# Find all files above a size and truncate?

Tags: linux, shell

Running cPanel on a server with various customer accounts under the `/home` directory.
Many customers' `error_log` files are exceeding a desired size (let's say 100MB) and I want to create a cron job to run daily to truncate any files over a certain size.

I know truncate can shrink files but it will extend files if they're smaller than the stipulated amount, so does my solution below (of first finding all files above the desired size and only shrinking those) make the most sense and will it work?

```
for i in $(find /home -type f -iname error_log -size +99M); do
    truncate -s 100M $i
done
```

Comment: `error_log files` Why not use a dedicated logging tool that handles that like `logrotate` instead or redirect the tool (I guess apache) logging to journalctl?

Comment: You should not EVER do `for i in $(subshell) ; do ...`. Especially do not do this if the subshell returns file names. Instead, in this case, use `find` with `-exec`. In the general case for find when `-exec` is not enough use the construct `while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do ... done < <(find ... -print0)`

Comment: Speaking to sorpigal's advice, see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) describing the problem, and [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) describing what to do instead.

Comment: For another way to break your logs down into smaller files (where rotating out old ones can just mean deleting old files), see [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html). Though on a modern Linux you'll have journald out-of-the-box, and that'll do all the work for you if you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [rotating and compressing logs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) rather than truncating them. Logs typically compress really well, and you can move the compressed logs to backup media if you like. Plus, if you do have to delete anything, delete the oldest logs, not the newest ones.

---

That said, for educational purposes let's explore `truncate`. It has the ability to only shrink files, though it's buried in the documentation:

> SIZE may also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters: '+' extend by, '-' reduce by, '<' at most, '>' at least, '/' round down to multiple of, '%' round up to multiple of.

If the files are at a fixed depth you don't need the loop nor the `find` call. A simple glob will do:

```
truncate -s '<100M' /home/*/path/to/error_log
```

If they're at unpredictable depths you can use extended globbing...

```
shopt -s extglob
truncate -s '<100M' /home/**/error_log
```

...or use `find -exec <cmd> {} +`, which tells `find` to invoke a command on the files it finds.

```
find /home -name error_log -exec truncate -s '<100M' {} +
```

(If there are lots and lots of files `find` is safest. The glob options could exceed Linux's command-line length limit whereas `find` guards against that possibility.)

Answer (score 3):

- Do not use `for i in $(...)`. It will break on whitespaces.
- Always quote your variable expansions. Do `"$i"`.
- `find` has `-exec`, just use it.

So:

```
find /home -type f -iname error_log -size +99M -exec truncate -s 100M {} \;
```